# Swift fetch minutes per kilometer from seconds per meter

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have an array of `CLLocations` each with the seconds per meter element. I want to calculate the run splits from that array (Minutes per kilometer). How can I fetch the minutes per kilometer for each kilometer from the `CLLocations` array?

This is how I am getting the locations below.

```
let query = HKWorkoutRouteQuery(route: route) { (_, locations, _, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("There was an error fetching route data: ", error)
            return
        }

        guard let locations = locations else { return }
    }
    healthStore.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLLocationSpeed` is defined as speed in meters per second, see [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationspeed)

It is an alias for `Double`, so you can just translate it with:

```swift
let speedMS = location.speed
let speedKMM = speedMS * 3 / 50
```

You can use an extension for better code readability:

```swift
extension CLLocationSpeed {
    func toKmM() -> Double {
        return self * 3 / 50
    }
}
```

And when you want to get km/m, you just use `CLLocation.speed.toKmM()`

**Edit:**
And even simpler solution by @Leo Dabus, extend CLLocation:

```swift
extension CLLocation { 
    var kilometersPerMinute: Double { 
        speed * 0.06 
    } 
}
```

Comment: How would I go about calling this every kilometer that passes?

Comment: I added an extension you can use, each time you want to get the speed km/h you should call `toKmH()`

Comment: I'm trying to get KM/M (kilometers per minute)

Comment: @GaryHost `speed * 0.06`

Comment: @GaryHost, sorry I read km/h, it should be 3/50 instead of 18/5 for km/m. I will edit the answer

Comment: @LeoDabus be careful, the ratio is `0.06`, not `0.6`

Comment: it was a typo 60 / 1000

Comment: Btw why don't you extend CLLocation instead of Double? And make it a computed property *you don't need to pass any parameters. `extension CLLocation { var kilometersPerMinute: Double { speed * 0.06 }
}`

Comment: I guess it makes more sense to extend CLLocation, I took this from a project where I required the original speed in m/s

Answer (score 1):

You can also create your own speed unit extending UnitSpeed. The advantage of doing it this way is that you can associate a symbol and gain much more control over the conversions:

```
extension UnitSpeed {
    static var metersPerMinute: UnitSpeed = .init(symbol: "m/min", converter:  UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1 / 60))
    static var kilometersPerMinute: UnitSpeed = .init(symbol: "km/min", converter:  UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 50 / 3))
}
```

---

```
let metersPerSecond = Measurement<UnitSpeed>(value: 30, unit: .metersPerSecond)
let kilometersPerHour = metersPerSecond.converted(to: .kilometersPerHour)      // 107.9999136000691 km/h
let kilometersPerMinute = metersPerSecond.converted(to: .kilometersPerMinute)  // 1.7999999999999998 km/min
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.unitStyle = .medium
formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.string(from: kilometersPerHour)      // "108 km/h"
formatter.string(from: kilometersPerMinute)    // "1.8 km/min"

UnitSpeed.kilometersPerMinute.converter.value(fromBaseUnitValue: 1) // 0.06
```

Comment: I wish one could simply write `UnitLength.meters / UnitDuration.minutes`, as the whole reason I suggested using the Units was to avoid hard-coding the unit relationships. Ole Begemann does similar work here: https://oleb.net/blog/2016/07/measurements-and-units/ But I thought it was too complicated to recommend for such a simple question :)